For loop: signed / unsigned integer expression WARNING
I have a shape Rectangle which consists of the following parameters:
int16_t x;
int16_t y;
uint16_t w;
uint16_t h;

x and y are int16_t's because the rectangle can also start from a negative position
w and h are uint16_t's because the rectangle can only have a positive width and height. (In theory it could also have a negative width and height but in my program this is not possible, in such a case the coordinates x and y are decremented accordingly)
Now my actual problem: When painting the rectangle (pixel by pixel) I implemented the following loops:
for(int16_t y_counter = y; y_counter < y+h; y_counter++) {
    for(int16_t x_counter = x; x_counter < x+w; x_counter++) {
        // ... draw pixel
    }
}

The problem now is that I have the compiler warning -Wsign-compare enabled which gives me the following warning:

warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

Now I am thinking what could be the most elegant (/most correct) solution to avoid this warning.
I came up with the following solution:
for(int16_t y_counter = y; y_counter < y+(int16_t)h; y_counter++) {
    for(int16_t x_counter = x; x_counter < x+(int16_t)w; x_counter++) {
        // ... draw pixel
    }
}

This eliminates the warning. But I have two concerns:

It doesn't look nice and therefore not very well readable
It is very unprobable but a rectangle could be starting at a negative coordinate and be larger then what a int16_t can hold. In such a case this would lead to an overflow

I know I could just ignore/disable this warning or leave it as it is but I was wondering if somebody came up with an elegant solution

Just don't use unsigned types (except for bit manipulation). They don't help prevent any errors (what would be an invalid negative value is now an invalid large value).

@HolyBlackCat Rather, don't use any signed types except when you actually need signed values. There's a lot of situations in C where misusing a signed type leads to blatant UB (overflow, negative array indexing, left-shifting into the sign bit, accidental sign extension etc etc) whereas the unsigned equivalent just leads to confusing results but without tearing down the whole house.

Using signed width and height is the default approach opencv takes with cv::Rect. And this implementation works quite well IMHO.

@Lundin "negative array indexing" - with underflowed unsigned value you'll be out of bounds anyway. "left-shifting into the sign bit" - with unsigned this becomes an out-of-range shift which is also UB. But yeah, I guess my "don't help prevent any errors" was a bit too strong.

@HolyBlackCat With unsigned arithmetic you could do bounds checking/defensive programming though, to see if the value is out of range. With signed integers you can't, because then the program has already invoked UB.

To be very clear here, this is one of those warnings that's not a warning, but an actual ticking bomb just waiting to blow up. C (and by extension C++) are particularly stupid about signed types, especially comparing them: for example, -1 is greater than 0U.  Never use unsigned types in C/C++. The language simply is not designed to work with them, no matter how logical they may seem to use.

Using unsigned types doesn't remove the need to ensure indices are in range, it changes, not eliminates, the checks needed to keep in valid range.   Practically, you would be better off simply using a signed integer (even in cases where it will only contain positive values).  Also, for array indices, int is always sufficient and usually preferable (e.g. int is the "native" type, so operations on it tend to be optimised (e.g. performance-wise), support of *int16_t types is also OPTIONAL, not all implementations support it`)


It doesn't look nice and therefore not very well readable

Nah it's fine. Explicit casts are easy to read. It's probably a worse offense to readability to use a verbose name for the loop iterator, you could as well have named them i and j since the "counter" part doesn't really add any valuable information. This is perfectly readable:
for(int16_t i=y; i < y + (int16_t)h; i++) {
    for(int16_t j=x; j < x + (int16_t)w; j++) {
        // ... draw pixel (i, j)
    }
}

Or if you are overly pedantic about keeping expressions simple:
int16_t y_limit = y + (int16_t)h;
int16_t x_limit = x + (int16_t)w

for(int16_t i=y; i < y_limit; i++) {
    for(int16_t j=x; j < x_limit; j++) {
        // ... draw pixel (i, j)
    }
}


It is very unprobable but a rectangle could be starting at a negative coordinate and be larger then what a int16_t can hold. In such a case this would lead to an overflow

If you worry about that, you probably shouldn't have been using small integer types to begin with. They do come with an implicit promotion to int on 32/64 bit system, which is unfortunate. Switching everything to int32_t would probably have been a sensible fix to that and also resolves the warning.

for(int32_t y_counter = y; y_counter < y+static_cast<int32_t>(h); y_counter++) {
  for(int32_t x_counter = x; x_counter < x+static_cast<int32_t>(w); x_counter++) {
    // ... draw pixel
  }
}

just use 32 bit signed ints.  They are large enough to both hold 16 bit signed and unsigned ints, and their sums.
On most platforms, your math ends up being done in 32 bits and converted back anyhow.
This is also one of the few ways to ensure correctness if you are actually using all 16 bits of your unsigned width/height.
...
I personally avoid doing manual for loops that are anything but for(auto x = start; x != end; ++x).  To that end, I have integer ranges:
for(auto y_counter : range_start_length<int32_t>(y, h))
  for(auto x_counter : range_start_length<int32_t>(x, w))
    // draw pixel

which describes the iteration by describing a range, then iterates over it.
The goal is to avoid non-trivial computation in the body of a for(;;) loop, which I find is often missed by people reading the code (and error prone).  The work to ensure a correct loop bound is now done in one spot, which can be unit tested, and used in many spots.

Unless you're facing severe memory constraints, this is the way to do it.

I agree this fixes problem 2 (which is very unprobably in my opinion). But it does not solve the "problem" of readability/elegance. With your static_cast it is even more unreadable in my opinion...

I might have removed the C++ tag prematurely, I didn't realize there were C++ answers posted.

@ThomasSparber (int16_t) style casts can do anything up to and including reinterpreting a pointer to be a 16 bit integer, so I advise avoiding them.  The problem of readability/elegance is that you are using unsigned integers (apparently without need): an unsigned integer is not "an integer restricted to not being negative" in practice.  It is an integer value mod 2^16.

@Lundin guess why I added the Tag... ;-)

@ThomasSparber No the tag shouldn't have been used in the first place, since nothing in your question is unique to C++, nor is about the differences/portability between the languages. Answers in C and C++ may be different, however. If you are truly interested in answers for both languages, then you could post two different questions.

I'll switch the tag to C++ to be fair to this answer.

To avoid the warning you can rewrite the for loop
for(int16_t y_counter = y; y_counter < y+h; y_counter++) {
    for(int16_t x_counter = x; x_counter < x+w; x_counter++) {
        // ... draw pixel
    }
}

for example the following way
for(int32_t y_counter = y, height = h; y_counter < y+height; y_counter++) {
    for(int32_t x_counter = x, width = w; x_counter < x+width; x_counter++) {
        // ... draw pixel
    }
}

